# c++ Cannot open include file when file location is correct

Tags: c++, cmake

I have been trying to include Botan files into my project, but so far, it hasn't been working because it can't find the files. I am using Clion IDE with Cmake and in the CmakeLists.txt file, I have included the relative path to the files I want to add:

```
include_directories(./Botan/include)
```

From there, I want to add the sha2_64.h file to one of my header files, so I have the following in my header file:

```
#include <botan/sha2_64.h>
```

The autofill worked properly in Clion and it found `botan/sha2_64.h` but when it came time to build the project, I get the error "Cannot open include file: 'botan/sha2_64.h': No such file or directory" Why can the autofill find the file, but the compiler can't? I even tried accessing the file by using:

```
#include "../Botan/include/botan/sha2_64.h" //Relative path from my header file to sha2_64.h
```

This still resulted in the file not being found. I know that this path is correct as Clion's autofill finds it no problem. I just can't figure out why the compiler can't find the file.

Comment: Try `#include "botan/sha2_64.h"`

Comment: Same error occurs, can't find the file

Comment: Check case sensitivity. `Botan` vs `botan`

Comment: The case sensitivity is correct. The folder with the Botan files in it, the first one, is Botan, with a capital B and the second one is botan with a lower case b. Again, these were both added by the Clion autofill, so Clion confirmed that this is in fact the correct path to the file.

Comment: From what you have written in your question, try `#include "./Botan/include/botan/sha2_64.h` (or even just plain `#include "Botan/include/botan/sha2_64.h"`)

Comment: https://github.com/randombit/botan/issues/1453